# YouTube won't load my watch history past a certain amount of videos

Tags: youtube

Youtube cuts off my watch history at certain date and won't load anymore videos I've watched.

Furthermore, anytime I watch a new video YouTube removes the oldest video from the history. This is happening across all my devices including the mobile app and PC and on different browsers as well. I have never deleted my watch history and I have auto delete turned off.

I've tried deleting my cache and disabling u-block origin but it still won't load. I'm not sure why youtube started doing this. Before this glitch, I could scroll to see my full watch history. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not a solution to that *specific* problem, but you can view your entire watch history here; https://www.youtube.com/feed/history

Comment: This link also provides a complete watching history along with a calendar; https://myactivity.google.com/product/youtube?utm_source=sidenav So you don't need to endlessly scroll down to find something you watched x years ago

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional details: **1.** Confirm you are talking about behavior in the web application, not another app such as Android/IOS, etc.  **2.** What auto-delete options do you have set in [YouTube Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/product/youtube)? **2.** What do you actually see in the [YouTube Watch History](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history) (per Valorum's comment)? i.e. provide more information about what is there and what happens to that information when you watch another video.  Let us know how far back your history goes in months or numbers.

Comment: @Valorum that *should* be the specific problem (history missing from  [YouTube Watch History](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history)).  Perhaps this question 
 It is not about the web application; if OP clarifies, we can migrate appropriately or point them to the right site.

Comment: @Blindspots On web browser and app, I could scroll down infinitely to see my full watch history. Now YouTube will only load it to a certain length and won't show any video beyond that length. My full YouTube history in my activity is still there so it's not as if it has deleted anything from it. I tried switching browsers but the problem still remains.

Comment: That is good info. Please [edit] it into your question.

Comment: I've edited it. Do you have this problem too?

Comment: No, I do not have the problem you described.  Does it seem that it is your infinite scroll that isn't working?

Comment: ***"My full YouTube history in my activity is still there"*** It is still unclear to me the problem.  **MyActivity** for YouTube, [myactivity.google.com/product/youtube](https://myactivity.google.com/product/youtube), redirects to [youtube.com/feed/history](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history) which is the same target as **YouTube menu > You > History** or  **Home > History** etc.  What is the way you could access it before?  Do I see a different GUI than you?  Can you [edit] to include some screenshots that identify what is missing and from where?

Comment: The problem is that when I go onto YouTube  and go History and scroll down it reaches a limit and won't show any videos beyond that point even though I have way more watch history than that. The glitch resolved itself temporarily today with the new update but then it glitched out again and won't load my full history, it just cuts off

Comment: @galacticninja What do I do if my question hasn't gotten an answer?

Comment: @Tito See: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/162827)

Comment: @galacticninja Should this question be on android enthusiasts instead?

Comment: I wouldn't crosspost as per "[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/162827)". If you're gonna ask in Android SE, make sure to phrase your question to be specific to Android, and add information, like screenshots of the issue.

Comment: @Tito Why'd you remove the screenshot in this question, by the way?

Comment: @galacticninja Because it didn't really give enough information. Is there a way I can post a screen recording instead?

Comment: So if I phrase the question in a different way, I won't get in trouble for asking it in another community?

Comment: @Tito As long as it's a different question, it's fine. If it's pretty much the same question, that might be considered crossposting and is not allowed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151787/discussion-between-galacticninja-and-tito).

Comment: Also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/256452/44325